# Error I am getting when I started recording

Tags: jmeter

When I click on Start button to start script from browser,I am getting an error message like

Root CA certificate:ApacheJmetertemporaryRootCA?

Answer (score 0):

Does `jMeter` creates that certificate?
Perhaps you should stick with the latest version of `jMeter`